# Nuxt 3 image src binding

Tags: nuxtjs3, supabase, nuxt3

I am trying to render an avatar image using Nuxt3.
So far I have

```
    <template>
       ...
       <img :src="avatarUrl.value"/>
       ...
    </template>

    <script setup>
    const avatarUrl = ref('')

    const {data: {user: currentUser}} = await supabase.auth.getUser()

    onMounted(async () => {
      if (currentUser) {
        let {data, error} = await supabase.from('Profiles').select('avatar_url').eq('user_id', currentUser.id).single()

        // Logs the correct url. eg: 
        // https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/[...]fsV4=s96-c
        console.log(data.avatar_url)

        if (!error) avatarUrl.value = data.avatar_url
      }
    })
    </script>
```

But the image won't display.
The rendered html is `<img data-v-inspector="components/Header.vue:55:15">`, so it doesn't even have a src.

How to dynamically render the img using the src received from the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the fix. I had to use `<img :src="avatarUrl"/>`.